# Check if a Cell Value is between Two Values using Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

In Excel, I have a table as follows, which shows pricing based on volume.

If you buy up to 4 items per month, the unit price is $100, 5 to 8 is $90, 9 to 20 is $80, anything above 20 is $50.

```
A |   B   | C 
----------------
1 |   4   | 100
5 |   8   | 90
9 |   20  | 80
21|  1000 | 50
```

I have my monthly purchase volumes in another column, say d:

```
D
--
3
6
2
4
3
10
7
7
10
2
```

I need to find the unit prices (C column values) based on this series falling between the values of A and B columns. I know I can use a compound if statement like `=IF(AND(D$1>=A1,B1>=D$1),C1,0) ...` but since my pricing table is actually much larger than my example, this approach becomes convoluted. How can I do this with a Vlookup in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go with the following in `E1`:

```
=INDEX(C$1:C$4,MATCH(D1,A$1:A$4))
```

which, at worst should be just as fast as `VLOOKUP` but at best is much faster.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! I will accept it as the right answer but please edit the `;` in your `match` function to `,`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by dragging the following formula down to cover the full column D:

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/($A$2:$A$5<=D2)/($B$2:$B$5>=D2),$C$2:$C$5)
```

This will take each D value, compare with A and B, locate which bucket it falls into, and pull the C value. If not found, will return an N/A.

Comment: Another approach is SUMIFS.

Comment: @BigBen can you please give an example of that approach? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using SUMIFS:

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C$4,$A$1:$A$4,"<="&E1,$B$1:$B$4,">="&E1)
```

[image]